# Derivative of $h(x,y) = \lambda f(x) + \mu g(y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ be open and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. Suppose $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is differentiable at $a$, and $g: B \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is differentiable at $b$. Define $h: A \times B \to \mathbb{R}^k$ by $h(x,y) = \lambda f(x) + \mu g(y)$ where $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that $h'(a,b)$ exists and is the $k \times (m + n)$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda f'(a) & \mu g'(b) \end{bmatrix}$?

I tried to unravel the definition of the derivative but I found it quite complex and wasn't able to do much.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you. I would appreciate if someone can suggest how to go about proving it, e.g. if there is just something simple I didn't notice.

Comment: Better, show that this matrix satisfies the standard limit definition of a multivariable function. (See my YouTube lectures linked in my profile if needed.)

Comment: @Ted Thank you.

Comment: Oops. Limit definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these cases, one useful "trick" is to invoke the use of the projection functions $\pi_1:\Bbb{R}^m \times \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$ and $\pi_2:\Bbb{R}^m \times \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$. Then, we can write:
\begin{align}
h &= \lambda \cdot (f \circ \pi_1) + \mu \cdot (g \circ \pi_2)
\end{align}
From here, let's apply the sum and scalar multiple rule of derivatives:
\begin{align}
Dh_{(a,b)} &= \lambda \cdot D(f\circ \pi_1)_{(a,b)} + \mu \cdot D(g\circ \pi_2)_{(a,b)}
\end{align}
Now, we have to calculate the derivative of a composition, so the chain rule is very handy here:
\begin{align}
D(f\circ \pi_1)_{(a,b)} &= Df_{\pi_1(a,b)} \circ D(\pi_1)_{(a,b)} \\
&= Df_a \circ \pi_1,
\end{align}
where in the last line I used the definition of $\pi_1$, and the fact that $\pi_1$ is a linear transformation so it is equal to its derivative at any point. Similarly, we have that $D(g\circ \pi_2)_{(a,b)} = Dg_b \circ \pi_2$. Putting this all together,
\begin{align}
Dh_{(a,b)} &= \lambda \cdot Df_a \circ \pi_1 + \mu \cdot Dg_b \circ \pi_2
\end{align}
This is the equation which expresses the derivative as a linear transformation. Now, if you want everything in terms of "Jacobian matrices", then all you have to do is express these linear transformations as matrices using the standard ordered bases on the domain $\Bbb{R}^{m}\times \Bbb{R}^n \cong \Bbb{R}^{m+n}$ and the target $\Bbb{R}^{k}$. Then, we have:
\begin{align}
h'(a,b) &= \lambda \cdot f'(a) \cdot [\pi_1] + \mu \cdot g'(b) \cdot [\pi_2]
\end{align}
Here, $h'(a,b)$ is the matrix representation of $Dh_{(a,b)}$, and $f'(a)$ is the $k\times m$ matrix representation of $Df_a:\Bbb{R}^m \to \Bbb{R}^k$, and $[\pi_1]$ is the $m \times (m+n)$ matrix representation of $\pi_1:\Bbb{R}^m\times \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$ etc, and the $\cdot$ which appears above is scalar mulitplication and also multiplication of matrices (because composition of linear maps corresponds to multiplication of their respective matrices).

It is now a simple matter to calculate what the matrices $[\pi_1]$ and $[\pi_2]$ look like. If you do so, then you immediately get
\begin{align}
h'(a,b) &=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda f'(a) & \mu g'(b)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
(I leave this last bit of simple linear algebra to you).

---

Of course, this isn't the only way to do things. You could also use the fact that if $\phi:\Bbb{R}^p \to \Bbb{R}^q$ is a differentiable map, then the matrix entries of $\phi'(\alpha)$ is the various partial derivatives $(D_j\phi_i)(\alpha)$. But I don't particularly like this method because I always forget which of $i,j$ corresponds to rows/columns, and by the time I figure this out, I can usually already get the answer using the above method. Also, I think for such simple problems, it is completely unnecessary to invoke the use of partial derivatives, because it obscures what's going on.

Comment: Nice. I see that your approach also generalizes easily to any finite linear combination, and helps with seeing what's going on. I did try it by partial derivatives and you're right about it being unnecessary; I obscured myself among the symbols.